# Cincinnati Bengals All-Time leading tackler?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl

I was wondering if anyone could find out who this person is? I cannot find this information and would really like to know.

Answer (score 3):

[Pro Football Reference](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/) has the information you need.

From the home page, click "Teams", then "Cincinnati Bengals." At this point, you will be on the ["Cincinnati Bengals Franchise Encyclopedia" page](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/cin/). On this page, under the "Career Leaders" dropdown, click "Defense." From [there](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/cin/career-defense.htm), you can view and sort by a number of different categories. Given you are looking for the all-time leading tackler, you may sort by tackles (Tkl).

---

> [Who is the] Cincinnati Bengals All-Time leading tackler?

Tim Krumrie with 1008 tackles.